# Add spacing between numbers after some specific digits in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput, letter-spacing

I need to show dashes as hints and need to have equal spacing after some digits in Text Input similar to the picture attached [image].
Do I need to use separate text inputs for these or is it possible to achieve this in a single input text field? The user should be able to enter the number in a single go.

Answer (score 0):

If you know phone number format you can do it manually in one input. You are saving it as a real number, but displaying it with spaces. If you can have various formats, from various countries you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-phone-number-input

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is by using mask input you can use `react-native-mask-input` library to do it you can check the library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mask-input).

[image]